# Error uploading file in website using move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, file

I am having an permission denied working while trying to upload files using move_uploaded_file() function in my website. Here is the error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(../photographs/17_zombie-house-design.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\inetpub\vhosts\skpaul.net\httpdocs\admin\upload_photo.php on line 78

---

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php61E1.tmp' to '../photographs/17_zombie-house-design.jpg' in D:\inetpub\vhosts\skpaul.net\httpdocs\admin\upload_photo.php on line 78

but the code I am using is working fine in local machine using WAMP
[image]

Comment: seems you have not the right permission on your remote server, you should check it with a terminal acces and `ls -al` command

Comment: set write permissions to the upload dir.